# Passing information from a UserFrom to another Sub/Function/Module using buttons and the OnClick event

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Within a Excel File, I have a **UserForm** which is opened by clicking on a custom button on the ribbon at the top, where you can select a file from the dropdown menu. 
There is a button below the Dropdown, which starts a VBA script that handles that file in a way, that is not relevent to this question.
Now my way of doing it was, assigning a sub to the button on the top of the ribbon, that opens the **UserForm**, and then assigning another sub to the button, which is called by the inbuilt click event handler.
My question is, is there a better way of dealing with this?

```
'button onclick code
Private Sub myButton_Click()
    Me.Hide
    SubDealingWithFile (cmbxFirstExcelfile.Text)
End Sub

'sub on ribbon
Sub RibbonSub(control As IRibbonControl)
    Dim form1 As myForm
    Set form1 = myForm
    form1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems fine to me.  Do you have concerns about your approach?

Comment: idk, seems kinda redundant in a way. like i have to go through 3 different subs, to accomplish one goal. i dont know if that is neccesarily the most optimal approach

Comment: that is true and especially true for myself (ive got a very strong temperament) however giving unsufficient explaination can come off as whoever is giving that explaination is looking down on you. so in that case it might be really better to not give any explaination at all, or go in more detail (quoting parts of the question, if it is infact a question and not just plain code may also help)